# Can't start ElasticSearch on WIn10 Pro

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm new to ElasticSearch. I downloaded the ElasticSearch-5.1.2.zip, and run the bin\elasticsearch.bat  (I didn't change any configurations).

However, the ES is blocked after loading plugins (actually, there's no plugin at all). And I can see from the Task Manager, the "Java Platform SE binary" process is still running as the CPU usage is about 15%. I have at least waited for one hour, but nothing happened.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with it?

[image]

**My Evnrionment**

- Win 10 Pro Insider Preview x64 (Build 15007)
- JDK 1.8.0_73

Comment: can you please share your logs for elasticsearch?

Comment: which log do you need? The content of the elasticseach.log is exactly the same as the console. And the content of the elasticsearch_deprecation.log is "[WARN ][o.e.d.s.g.GroovyScriptEngineService] [groovy] scripts are deprecated, use [painless] scripts instead", Other logs are empty.

Answer (score 0):

Check firewall settings. 
ES try to create transport service on port 9300 and cluster service on port 9200.

Comment: Thanks, I turned off the real-time protection of firewall (i.e Windows Defender). but still the same.